# Transpose data if on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, transpose

On Google sheets, I wish to transpose data from one sheet to another sheet. I wish to transpose each row which contains a date which is equal to today.

For example, in the below caase:

```
PO            | Ship Date
----------------------------------------------
754726        | 12/02/9009
754727        | TODAY()
754728        | 12/02/9009
754729        | TODAY()
7547210       | 12/02/9009
```

the data being transposed is:

```
PO            | Ship Date
----------------------------------------------
754727        | TODAY()
754729        | TODAY()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=query(Sheet1!A2:B,"select A,B where B = date """&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" ")
```